# Launch Google Chrome in Fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to auto start Chrome in Full Screen mode (F11) every time in asp.net webform

Same as when we do F11 key event.

Comment: I didn't get what you're trying to do? open chrome in full screen in what situation?

Comment: Are you asking through c# ?

Comment: I'm on the asp.net project. when I run web-form I need to get it full screen

Comment: @ Litisqe Kumar yes I want to do it using C# , 
is it easy JavaScript or C#?

Comment: You cannot launch Chrome in fullscreen. That requires user consent.

Comment: @marekful  if you know how to do it.. please explain

Comment: I wrote "you cannot". So what to explain? However, @Pranay Rana's answer is probably good.Still not _launching_ straight in fullscreen, but after launch, make it fullscreen.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.. Bus still I could not find a solution for my problem.. :(

Comment: The closest I've found is using the `--app=` switch, but it doesn't respect any other switches that I can see (that are relevant), such as `--start-maximized` or `--kiosk`, and I'm unsure of switches to kill minimize, resize and close buttons. Not looking promising. There'll be a way, doubtless, but perhaps not easily and reliably programmatically: might be one of the manual suggestions found across the web, programmatically opened, where you find your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function goFullscreen(id) {
            // Get the element that we want to take into fullscreen mode
            var element = document.getElementById(id);

            // These function will not exist in the browsers that don't support fullscreen mode yet, 
            // so we'll have to check to see if they're available before calling them.

            if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                // This is how to go into fullscren mode in Firefox
                // Note the "moz" prefix, which is short for Mozilla.
                element.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                // This is how to go into fullscreen mode in Chrome and Safari
                // Both of those browsers are based on the Webkit project, hence the same prefix.
                element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
            // Hooray, now we're in fullscreen mode!
        }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="goFullscreen('Button1'); return false"/>
```

It will appear like this on button click
[image]

Comment: That is not _fullscreen_. It's just a resized windowed mode.

Comment: I have Updated the answer. Check it and let me know if it is working.

Comment: But it's working. I have tested in Google chrome Version(43.0.2357.130 m)

Comment: can I do it Page load

Comment: I don't think it's possible to trigger it when the page loads, because it needs to be attached to an event handler on a page element (a button click, for instance). But least Try calling Button1.OnClientClick = "goFullscreen('Button1'); return false"; on Page Load

Comment: @Litisqe Kumar Thank you for advice.. 
and thank you all